# App icon not showing with notification while app is not active

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications

I don't know why this problem happens. When I use the app (active mode) the notification with the app icon is displaying properly into the status bar.

[image]

But while the app is in the background or not active the notification icon is an oval icon instead of the app icon. I don't know why this happening.

Please help

[image]

Comment: is the notification sent on notification or data block?

Answer (score 0):

You must define icon in Manifest meta data, 
try:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"  android:resource="@drawable/ic_notification" />
```